# How to validate the input type to receive integer only?

Tags: c, validation

I only want to receive integer from the user and I tried doing as the code below but it doesn't seems to be quite right.

```
int num;

printf("What is the ID?\n>> ");
        while(!scanf("%d", &num)){
            // consume new line
            getchar();
            printf("\nInvalid ID please try again...\n\n");
            printf("What is the ID?\n>> ");
        }
```

If I only input `a` into the `scanf`, it works fine, but when I input `ab` into the `scanf`, it loops 2 times and if i input 3 alphabet it will loops 3 times. Why is it?

```
What is the ID?
>> a

Invalid ID please try again...

What is the ID?
>> abc

Invalid ID please try again...

What is the ID?
>>
Invalid ID please try again...

What is the ID?
>>
Invalid ID please try again...

What is the ID?
>>
```

Comment: I realized that the problem is with the new line after the scanf. If i just write in 3 ```getchar()``` after the ```scanf``` it works fine, but I believe there should be a proper or better way to do it?

Comment: `getchar()` only consumes one character, you should use a loop to continue consuming characters until you have consumed the newline (or EOF). http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code needs to consume the non-numeric line of input.

Various ways to read the *rest of the line*

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
  ;
}
```

Or

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");  // read all non- \n
scanf("%*1[\n]");  // read 1 \n
```

---

Avoid below.  Fails to read anything when the next character is a `'\n'`.

```
scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int num;
char c;
printf("What is the ID?\n>> ");
    while(!scanf("%d", &num)){
        // consume new line
        gets(&c);
        printf("\nInvalid ID please try again...\n\n");
        printf("What is the ID?\n>> ");
    }
return 0;
}
```

By adding a gets() you can take in the new line and remove the issue.